# Nest a UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview of an array of images, it works for the images to scroll left and right but I cannot scroll down, instead I am able to scroll my tableview cells...I need to be able to scroll downwards and not have my array of images fixed on the view, is there any ways?

the codes i used are :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.frame = view.frame
    imageArray = [UIImage(named:"adsImage3")!,UIImage(named:"adsImage2")!,UIImage(named:"adsImage")!]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: 380)

        scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

}
```

as for my storyboard, it looks like:[image]

if I were to put my scrollview in my tableview, my code would be
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: MainMenuRowSelectionTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainMenuRowSelectionTableViewCell

```
    var cellColors = ["#FFB3B3","#FFFFFF"]
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: cellColors[indexPath.row % cellColors.count])

    imageArray = [UIImage(named:"adsImage3")!,UIImage(named:"adsImage2")!,UIImage(named:"adsImage")!]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
    }
    return cell
}
```

and my storyboard

[image]

this way,my scroll view wouldnt appear at all

Comment: You can use UICollectionView to display images in Grid format instead of using UIScrollView. It will solve scrolling problem and again it's easier way to implement functionality you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to be able to scroll downwards and not have my array of images fixed on the view

A table view *is* a vertical scroll view. You should turn your horizontal scroll view of images into the header view for the table view (i.e. its `tableHeaderView`), and make the table view occupy the whole screen. Now you can scroll the table and you'll scroll the scroll view of images up out of the screen.

Comment: I have done them, and but in the cellForRows, but it doesnt show my scroll views...it only shows the cells

Comment: @WilliamLoke I don't know what you're doing now. Perhaps you don't understand how to size and configure a table view's header view (i.e. its `tableHeaderView` property). But that would be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done. A good reference for nested scroll views is [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html) There is sample code available there as well.

In short, you will likely need to create:

1. A `UIScrollView` that fills the view and can scroll vertically,
2. A `UIScrollView` within that for the images and can scroll horizontally, and
3. Your `UITableView` also placed within the first scroll view.

[image]

Comment: u meant, to fill up the whole view with a scroll view,then put a tableview and fill up the scroll view?

Comment: Not exactly, one scroll view would fill the screen, the other two scrollable views would be within it. See screen shot above. That said, I would try @matt 's solution first. This might be another alternative though.